# Running Launchd Services with Non Root User on macOS

Tags: macos, big-sur, launchd, services, monterey

I am building a launchctl service which can run a java service. I am able to create launchctl service with root user and test start/stop/status/automatic start at reboot use cases.

I am struggling with running same launchctl service with non root user(`ec2-user` in my case)

My `plist` file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>siem</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>java</string>
    <string>-jar</string>
    <string>/Users/ec2-user/siem.jar</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/> <!-- run the program at login -->
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/> <!-- run the program again if it terminates -->
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/Users/ec2-user</string>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mycommand.err</string>
   <key>StandardOutPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mycommand.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried various steps to run the above service with `ec2-user`. UID for `ec2-user` is 501.

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Bootstrap failed: 125: Unknown error: 125
```

Verified the content of plist file

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % plutil ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
/Users/ec2-user/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist: OK
```

Tried bootstraping service with `user`

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl bootstrap user/501 ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
```

All of the above errors are not verbose and doesn't seem to find any way.

**My goal : I want to run launchctl service with non root user.**

**Environment Details:**

**OS** : macOS on AWS EC2 Instance

**macOS Version** : BigSur and Monterey

**Update 1:**

Checked system logs

```
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem[2159]): Service could not initialize: 20G224: xpcproxy + 23787 [839][86D1F823-583D-36B7-A047-55971A034143]: 0xd
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem.label[2160]): Service could not initialize: 20G224: xpcproxy + 23787 [839][86D1F823-583D-36B7-A047-55971A034143]: 0xd
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem[2159]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem.label[2160]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
Nov 26 17:51:23 ip-172-31-30-212 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (siem.label): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Comment: You might need the full java path. Been a while since I checked which path it uses by default, but like cron, launchdaemons don't get a lot. check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927956/launchd-managing-a-java-jar

Comment: Gave the full path of java also, It is not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Used tool `LaunchControl` to debug the problem. I recommend to install the `brew cask install launchcontrol`, which is a gui tool for launchctl, it can help detect errors and trouble shooting.

In my case, there were the following issues

- `StandardOutPath` and
  `StandardErrorPath` were given where my user had no write permissions
  with it.
- I started my service first with the root user thus service
  created logs location. Then I started the same service with another
  `non-root` user and as logs location were already created, the
  `non-root` user had no permission there to write on that.

The reason it took some time to figure out the above issues is the very poor error logging provided by macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the plist.

You need the key UserName

e.g.

```
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>ec2-user</string>
```

For more see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ

Comment: I have added that and ran commands and it is not working `ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Load failed: 5: Input/output error` and `ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error`